# Docker nodejs with mysql communication

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm using 2 docker images one with my nodeJS backend server the other with my MySQL database. On the docker-compose file I'm defining the passwords, ports and hostnames correctly:

```
sql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    hostname: sql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    secrets:
      - db_root_pass
      - db_user_pass
    environment: 
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_user_pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_pass
  provider:
    image: monokilho/app:dev
    hostname: provider
    ports:
      - 3000:3001
      - 9221:9229
    secrets:
      - db_user_pass
    command: node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 appModule.js
```

And on my DB_config.js file for NodeJS I have the connection setup like so:

```
db_config.host = 'sql';
db_config.port = '3306';
db_config.user = 'user';
db_config.password = fs.readFileSync('/run/secrets/db_user_pass', 'utf8');
db_config.database = 'app';
db_config.multipleStatements = true;
```

Problem is that although, using this exact configurations, docker connects Node to MySQL just fine on my local windows machine, when I upload the images to my remote linux server I continue to get:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'8b2e56e566b2.network_default'

I've already remade the secrets, tried manually adding the passwords to the config on NodeJS and nothing... what makes it even weirder is that if I go on the MySQL container to connect directly or if I make another MySQL container and remotely connect it works, so I know the password input on MySQL config is correct and it is accepting remote connections.

Any suggestion what might be the difference between windows and linux for this behavior to happen? Thanks in advance.

PS: If needed windows is windows 10 and linux distro is ububtu 16.04.

EDIT: The access denied error appears on the mysql logs so the nodejs docker can reach the mysql docker and the network should be fine.

Comment: Could it be the problem that your user for Node application doesn't have valid grant for Docker created network? Just an idea...

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify on the post that the access denied that i get is on the mysql logs, so the network is working fine and i can reach the server

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the mysql config was ignoring a sneaky \n on the password file allowing it to work normally with a command line connection, while on the nodejs it was bugging the connection.